# Google Sheets App Script Merge or Add New Row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code which gets data from two sheets but can't figure out how update or add a new row in sheet "sumTransaction" where Category, Month & Year are equal.

For example in this example Expense 1, January, 2019 exists in the sumTransaction sheet so it should update the amount value by -3.  Where Source A, January, 2019 and Other 1, March, 2019 do not exist in sumTransaction so they should be added to a new row.

```
function tableToObject() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const transactionSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Transactions')
  const lastRow = transactionSheet.getLastRow()
  const lastColumn = transactionSheet.getLastColumn()
  const values = transactionSheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn).getValues()
  const [headers, ...originalData] = values.map(([,b,,d,e,,,,,,,,,,,p,q,r,s]) => [b,d,e,p,q,r,s])
  const res = originalData.map(r => headers.reduce((o, h, j) => Object.assign(o, { [h]: r[j] }), {}))
  console.log(res)
 // GroupBy and Sum
 const transactionGroup = [...res.reduce((r, o) => {
 const key = o.Category + '_' + o.Month + '_' + o.Year
 const item = r.get(key) || Object.assign({}, o, {
   Amount: 0,
 })

  item.Amount += o.Amount
  item.Key = key
  return r.set(key, item)
}, new Map).values()]

 console.log(transactionGroup)

 const budgetValues = getBudget()
 console.log(budgetValues)

 // merge or add row

}

function getBudget(){
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 const sumSheet = ss.getSheetByName('sumTransacation')
 const lastRow = sumSheet.getLastRow()
 const lastColumn = sumSheet.getLastColumn()
 const values = sumSheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn).getValues()
 const [headers, ...originalData] = values.map(([a,b,c,d,e,f]) => [a,b,c,d,e,f])
 const res = originalData.map(r => headers.reduce((o, h, j) => Object.assign(o, { [h]: r[j] }), {}))
 return res
 }
```

transactionGroup Data

```
[ { Date: Fri Jan 04 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),
  Category: 'Source A',
  Amount: 85,
  Month: 'January',
  Year: 2019,
  Group: 'COGS',
  Debit: 'Credit',
  Key: 'Source A_January_2019' },
{ Date: Mon Feb 25 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),
  Category: 'Expense 1',
  Amount: -3,
  Month: 'February',
  Year: 2019,
  Group: 'Expense',
  Debit: 'Debit',
  Key: 'Expense 1_February_2019' },
{ Date: Tue Mar 26 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time),
  Category: 'Other 1',
  Amount: -4,
  Month: 'March',
  Year: 2019,
  Group: 'Other',
  Debit: 'Debit',
  Key: 'Other 1_March_2019' 
 } ]
```

budgetValues Data

```
 [ { Category: 'Expense 1',
   Month: 'January',
   Year: 2019,
   Group: 'COGS',
   Amount: 10,
   'Debit/Credit': '' },
{ Category: 'Expense 2',
   Month: 'January',
   Year: 2019,
   Group: 'COGS',
   Amount: 10,
   'Debit/Credit': '' } ]
```

Sample Image of sumTransactions Sheet ( i.e. before script )

[image]

Sample Image of sumTransactions Sheet ( i.e. after script )

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69669686/google-app-script-sum-values-from-1-tab-to-another-w-out-duplicate)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. What is "sumTransaction" sheet, "transactionGroup Data", "budgetValues Data", "Before logic" and "After logic" in your image?

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for the response, my explanation probably wasn't great.  The short of it is I'm trying to merge the information from transactionGroup Data into the sheet sumTransacation where Category, Month and Year are equal.  If there is not matching row with then add it to the sumTransaction sheet.  I've gotten as far as getting date but not sure how to merge it together and then update a matching row or adding a new one.  Does that help?  The screen shot was only showing in yellow what the sheet looked like first and in green after the script ran.  Note, there wouldn't be both or spaces.

Comment: @Cooper, thanks for pointing that one out.  It isn't exactly a duplicate, I've been able to get it further but the suggestion was to make a more specific question which was my attempt here.  I didn't see how to delete the old one, if possible.  Sorry saw the delete option now and did that.  Any suggestions on making more targets questions is appreciated.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. Where is "sumTransaction" sheet in your image? I cannot understand the relationship between "transactionGroup Data", "budgetValues Data", "Before logic" and "After logic". Can I ask you about the detail of your goal and the current issue of your script?

Comment: @Tanaike I uploaded two new screenshots showing the before and after for the sumTransactions sheet.  Everything up to console.log(transactionGroup) gets data from the transactions tab and groups it.  Then const budgetValues = getBudget() is gets values from the sumTransactions sheet.  I'm trying to take the data from transactionGroup and merge it into the sumTransactions sheet.  So if Expense 1, January, 2021 exists in the sumTransactions sheet add the amount value from transactionGroup where Expense 1, January, 2021.  Screenshot Expense 1 goes from 10 to 7 per the above data.

Comment: @Tanaike If per the data above if Source A, January, 2021 does not exist in the sumTransactions sheet then add a new row with this information.  See row 4 in the screenshot.  Note this data comes from transactionGroup.  Does this help at all?  Sorry about the screenshots, probably not so clear without the tabs before.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your values of `transactionGroup Data` and `budgetValues Data`, `Category: 'Expense 1'` of `transactionGroup Data` is `Month: 'February',`. And `Category: 'Expense 1'` of `budgetValues Data` is `Month: 'January',`. When I saw the images of `i.e. before script` and `i.e. after script`, why is `Category: 'Expense 1'` of `transactionGroup Data` removed? I cannot understand the logic for retrieving your output situation from your sample values. I deeply apologize for my poor understanding.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots showing how the data in the source sheets is structured? (otherwise, a copy of the spreadsheet could be equally valid).

Comment: @Tanaike sorry it took so long to get back. This is really awesome and it is almost there.  Below is the link to the spreadsheet. In the updated screenshot green is the original data on the sheet, blue is what was added by your script and yellow was the expected. I tried to break down what I think is happening unsuccessfully.  Once we have this working, I hope you don't mind a few follow up questions about the code so I can better understand it.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17SId7mIzO3hVOC36Nq40O0bjPS5YfGOX4wsMU1NlbCU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Tanaike Per my request to better understand. I'm not quite sure what Object.assign(o, { [`${r[0] + r[1] + r[2]}`]: r }), {}) is doing  or const temp = obj1[r[0] + r[1] + r[2]] or eturn r.slice(0, 4).concat([r[4] + temp[4], r[5]])

Comment: @Tanaike
One other thing, original there was column in sumTransaction called debit/credit but I removed it because an error was happening that said "The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 5 but the range has 6."  I understand the error and believe because values[0].length is 6 where values is 5 at setting values

Comment: @lamblichus
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17SId7mIzO3hVOC36Nq40O0bjPS5YfGOX4wsMU1NlbCU/edit#gid=1558847332

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- There are 2 sheets which are the source sheet `Transactions` and the destination sheet `sumTransacation`.
- You want to check the duplicated values between the source and destination sheets. At that time, you want to check the columns "A" to "C" on the destination sheet. So from your sample values, you want to check the values of `Category`, `Month`, and `Year`.
- From your explanation,

  - When I saw your values of `transactionGroup Data` and `budgetValues Data`, `Category: 'Expense 1'` of `transactionGroup Data` is `Month: 'February',`. And `Category: 'Expense 1'` of `budgetValues Data` is `Month: 'January',`. When I saw the images of `i.e. before script` and `i.e. after script`, `Category: 'Expense 1'` of `transactionGroup Data` is removed. In this case, I thought that you might want to add the value of `Category: 'Expense 1'` of `transactionGroup Data` to the destination sheet.

When my understanding is correct, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

I added the script's flow in the script as the comment.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  // 1. Retrieve values from destination sheet.
  const dst = ss.getSheetByName('sumTransacation');
  const [headers, ...dstVal] = dst.getDataRange().getValues();

  // 2. Retrieve values from source sheet.
  const src = ss.getSheetByName('Transactions');
  const [srcHead, ...srcVal] = src.getDataRange().getValues();
  const srcIdx = headers.reduce((ar, h) => {
    const temp = srcHead.indexOf(h);
    if (temp > -1) ar.push(temp);
    return ar
  }, []);
  const srcValues = srcVal.map(r => srcIdx.map(i => r[i]));

  // 3. Update values of destination sheet.
  const obj1 = srcValues.reduce((o, r) => Object.assign(o, {[`${r[0] + r[1] + r[2]}`]: r}), {});
  const values1 = dstVal.map(r => {
    const temp = obj1[r[0] + r[1] + r[2]];
    if (temp) {
      return r.slice(0, 4).concat([r[4] + temp[4], r[5]]);
    }
    return r;
  });

  // 4. Added new values of source sheet.
  const obj2 = dstVal.reduce((o, r) => Object.assign(o, {[`${r[0] + r[1] + r[2]}`]: r}), {});
  const values2 = srcValues.reduce((ar, r) => {
    if (!obj2[r[0] + r[1] + r[2]]) ar.push(r);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  const values = [headers, ...values1, ...values2];

  // 5. Update the destination sheet using new values.
  dst.clearContents().getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Edit:

When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I noticed that your spreadsheet is different from your sample images. I think that this is the reason of your issue. So for your sample Spreadsheet, I added one more sample script as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function sample2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  // 1. Retrieve values from destination sheet.
  const dst = ss.getSheetByName('sumTransacation');
  const [headers, ...dstVal] = dst.getDataRange().getValues();

  // 2. Retrieve values from source sheet.
  const src = ss.getSheetByName('Transactions');
  const [srcHead, ...srcVal] = src.getDataRange().getValues().map(([,b,,d,e,,,,,,,,,,,p,q,r,s]) => [b,d,e,p,q,r,s])
  const srcIdx = headers.reduce((ar, h) => {
    const temp = srcHead.indexOf(h);
    if (temp > -1) {
      ar.push(temp);
    } else {
      ar.push("");
    }
    return ar
  }, []);
  const srcValues = srcVal.map(r => srcIdx.map(i => r[i]));

  // 3. Update values of destination sheet.
  const obj1 = srcValues.reduce((o, r) => Object.assign(o, {[`${r[0] + r[1] + r[2]}`]: r}), {});
  const values1 = dstVal.map(r => {
    const temp = obj1[r[0] + r[1] + r[2]];
    if (temp) {
      return r.slice(0, 4).concat([r[4] + temp[4], r[5]]);
    }
    return r;
  });

  // 4. Added new values of source sheet.
  const obj2 = dstVal.reduce((o, r) => Object.assign(o, {[`${r[0] + r[1] + r[2]}`]: r}), {});
  const values2 = srcValues.reduce((ar, r) => {
    if (!obj2[r[0] + r[1] + r[2]]) ar.push(r);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  const values = [headers, ...values1, ...values2];

  dst.clearContents().getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- In your sample Spreadsheet, the values of "Month" of "Transactions" is different from that of "sumTransacation" sheet. But, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual format. So, when you want to compare the values, how about changing the format as the same format? Please be careful this.

Comment: @JAK Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I noticed that your spreadsheet is different from your sample images. I think that this is the reason of your issue. For this, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: thank you for all the help.  I'm sure you got more than you bargained for.

Comment: @JAK Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.